# nuget package restore failed in build pipeline after updating the visual studio 2017 to 2019 in build agent server

Tags: azure-devops

2020-04-23T07:13:09.4014026Z ##[error]Error: C:\BuildAgent_work_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1 2020-04-23T07:13:09.4014026Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore 2020-04-23T07:13:09.4170281Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet restore

Comment: How did you define your build definition? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you use an old `'NuGet` version. Pleae se change it to a newer or use installer task to install `4.0.0`

```yaml
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.0.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.0.0
```

But I would recommend to get rid of hardcoding nuget version in your pipeline. There is already `NuGet` tool but newer.